# make edit button with default message/data in input box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I have the table with edit button(green and blue)

[(pic)blue edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjv7c.png)   *the blue one can get exactly the right row of the table date which plain to edit*

[(pic)green edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtX3R.png)  *the green edit button can pop out the tiny window to import the value*

**Q: how can  we make `inside green edit button pop window` already default original data, that we can just change few data**

[(ideal pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0tKL.png) such as this one the default message is already in box

- the  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/item_all",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
            return response.ipcs
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
          {
            data: null,
            title: "edit",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return'<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit</button>   ';
            }
          },
          
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" },
          { data: "ip", title: "ip" },
          { data: "port", title: "port" },
          { data: "ipc_enable", title: "ipc_enable" },
          { data: "ftp_enable", title: "ftp_enable" },
          { data: "id", title: "id" },
          { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" },
          { data: "updated_at", title: "updated_at" }
        ]
      });


      table.draw()
      // Edit row function

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

        // console.log("GET edit ID", id)     
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });

      function editRow_website(id){
                 
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);
        var ip=document.getElementById("ip"+id);
        var port=document.getElementById("port"+id);
        var ipc_enable=document.getElementById("ipc_enable"+id);
        var ftp_enable=document.getElementById("ftp_enable"+id);
        var id=document.getElementById("id"+id);
        var created_at=document.getElementById("created_at"+id);
        var updated_at=document.getElementById("updated_at"+id);
        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,
          "name_data": ip,
          "email_data": port,
          "address_data": ipc_enable,
          "name_data": ftp_enable,
          "email_data": id,
          "address_dat": created_at,
          "address_dat": updated_at,

        }
        
      }
 

      function editRow(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/item_all?device_id="+ id,
          type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }

 
    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class ="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="z-index:999;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit mode</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input class="modalTextInput form-control" placeholder="Text Here" />

          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="saveEdit btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }
 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you need two edit buttons?

Comment: That were come from two demo I see on the web, cause I'm a beginner, that I did tried my best to make it work, but still lacking combine two function together, and also solve the `main` question.